# Error 500 when google indexing robots visits my website (IIS)

Tags: iis, dns, googlebot

I've developped a website in asp.net mvc3 and I'm thus hosting it on a windows server (OVH).

The domain name is registered with GoDaddy and I thus have edited the DNS record of type A to point to my OVH hosting server.

```
GoDaddy DNS records
-------------------
Host :      @   
Points to : [Server-IP]
TTL :       1 Hour          
    
Host :      www 
Points to : [Server-IP]
TTL :       1 Hour
```

Therefore I can visit the website but when Google Robot try to visit my website, it gets an error 500 (which means a server-side error), which cause my website not to be indexed by google, bing and other search engines.

I can view an error 500 every week in Google Webmaster Tools error log whan the robot try to index my website.

Do I have made a mistake while configuring the DNS record on GoDaddy? Or do I have to edit something in the IIS Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 usually means there is an error in your code. Check windows event logs for .NET exceptions or setup [ELMAH](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah) to log all uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Thanks I've been able to view exceptions with ELMAH, It was coming from me trying to access user languages in the httpcontext which exists not in a robot... :p

Thanks a lot !!